# Aligning Left Float Image with Two Stacking Text Boxes

Tags: html, css

Having difficulty aligning these images (clocks for now) with the text. Ideally, the text would be centered with the icon but that's not happening.

Website is yodega.com/sell.

The clocks also slowly lower as they go down the page (have NO idea how that happens).

Also, on web the images are below the text but on mobile the image are above the text. I believe I need to completely restructure this but not sure how to go about that. Appreciate greatly any thoughts.

```css
body {
  background: #3a3a3a;
}

p {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

html,
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
ul,
ol,
li,
p,
a {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #FAD48B;
  margin: 15px 0 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

h2 {
  color: #FAD48B;
  margin: 20px 0 5px 0;
  padding: 2px;
}

h3 {
  color: #FAD48B;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}


/*removes top nav put back once live!*/

.nav {
  display: none;
}


/*removes top nav !!put back once live!! */

.navbar-top-area.navbar-inverse {
  display: none;
}


/*removes menu !!put back once live!! */

.site-header .menu-container {
  display: none;
}


/* adds some yellow space below yodega loga in header*/

.site-header .container {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/*attepmt to fix header to top*/

.header {
  position: fixed;
}


/*sell title = title "Sell Food Online with Yodega"*/

.sell-title {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 55px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-weight: bold;
  line-height: 55px;
}


/*sets paramaters of smaller benefits icon*/

.benefit-icon {
  width: 20%;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.benefit-icon img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/*sets paramaters of larger benefits text*/

.benefit-title {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  Margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-decoration: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
}


/*sets paramaters of smaller benefits text*/

.benefit-detail {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.astericks {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 692pxpx) {
  .main,
  .small {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
}


/*changes outer background color of sign up form*/

#mailchimpsf_widget-2 {
  background: #3A3A3A;
}


/*changes signup form title font color*/

#mailchimpsf_widget-2 .widget-title {
  color: #FAD48C;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*removes signup box inner border*/

#mc_signup_form {
  border: none;
}


/*changes signup button colors*/

#mc_signup_submit {
  background: #FAD48C;
  color: #3A3A3A;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sell-title">Sell Food Online with Yodega</div>

<div>
  <div class="benefit-icon"><img src="http://www.yodega.com/images/blankClock.png" /></div>
  <div class="benefit-title blue">
    <div class="benefit-title blue"><b>Fast &amp; Easy Set Up – Start Selling Today</b></div>
  </div>
  <div class="benefit-detail purple">
    <div class="benefit-detail purple">store complete in 10 minutes with no programming required</div>
  </div>
  <div class="benefit-icon"><img src="http://www.yodega.com/images/blankClock.png" /></div>
  <div class="benefit-title blue">
    <div class="benefit-title blue"><b>Zero Set Up Cost: free Store &amp; Listings</b></div>
  </div>
  <div class="benefit-detail purple">
    <div class="benefit-detail purple">keep more of your money – only very small selling fees*</div>
  </div>
  <div class="benefit-icon"><img src="http://www.yodega.com/images/blankClock.png" /></div>
  <div class="benefit-title orange"><b>Your Own Personal Store – Custom URL &amp; Store</b></div>
  <div class="benefit-detail green">your own store page with direct web link</div>

  <div class="benefit-icon"><img src="http://www.yodega.com/images/blankClock.png" /></div>
  <div class="benefit-title orange"><b>Hassle-Free: Yodega Takes Care of Everything</b></div>
  <div class="benefit-detail green">you can focus on what you do best</div>
  <div class="benefit-icon"><img src="http://www.yodega.com/images/blankClock.png" /></div>
  <div class="benefit-title orange"><b>Reduce your fee rate with referrals</b></div>
  <div class="benefit-detail green">each seller you refer <b>permanently</b> reduces your fee rate**</div>
</div>

<div class="astericks">

  *4.9% + typical credit card processing fees **A vaild referral requires a recommendation within 1 month of referral store opening. Store must sell $300 of sales before referral rate reduction activates. Maximium .9% in reduction from standard fee rate
  from referral incentives.

</div>
```

Comment: Your `<div>` elements that contain the image have a fixed height that is greater than the image, and the image is leaking. Do you want to shrink the image, or increase the container? Also, you would benefit from combining **both** the title and content into a single parent `<div>` that is floated against the `<div>` on the left.

Comment: also you are using position:static on the text (try relative and display inline-block) and reduce the size of the headers (22px and 30px for headers/paragraphs.. even on mobile? use media queries to reduce according to screen size).. that's not to mention the 30px margin-top

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I've not used the relative inline-block or used media queries according to screen size but I'll look into that.

Comment: Shrinking the image could be useful. Ideally, the image would become the size of the container but not sure I have it set up that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will be helpful to you.

**Html**

```
<div class="div-main-container">
    <div class="div-left-side">
        <img src="blankClock.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="div-right-side">
        <div class="div-right-ele-heading">Fast & Easy Set Up – Start Selling Today</div>
        <div class="div-right-normal-text">store complete in 10 minutes with no programming required</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="div-main-container">
    <div class="div-left-side">
        <img src="blankClock.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="div-right-side">
        <div class="div-right-ele-heading">Fast & Easy Set Up – Start Selling Today</div>
        <div class="div-right-normal-text">store complete in 10 minutes with no programming required</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.clear{clear:both}
.div-main-container{width:100%}
.div-left-side{width:12%;float:left}
.div-right-side{width:80%;float:left;margin-top: 3%}
.div-right-normal-text{font-size: 15px;}
.div-right-ele-heading{color: #444;font-size: 20px;font-weight:800}
```

In above code if we will use **vertical-align: middle;** properties then this will not worked because here the height on the Text container is not fixed that's why we used **margin-top**.

If you wanted **text to be in middle of the image** then you need add **margin-top** to this class **.div-right-side**.

**In above code i have already added margin-top.**

**Mobile view changes**

```
@media(max-width:560px){
        .div-left-side {padding-top: 4%}
    }
    @media(max-width:767px){
        .div-left-side {width: 25%;}
        .div-left-side img{width: 80%}
        .div-right-side {width: 75%}
    }
    @media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:992px){
        .div-left-side {width: 25%;}
        .div-right-side {width: 75%;float: left;margin-top: 7%}
    }
```

Here i have used **@media** query for the mobile view as per the media query standard.

Comment: wow thanks a lot, I'll definitely use this!

I'm not seeing/understanding where to use margin-top.

Comment: If you wanted text to be in middle of the image then you need add margin-top to this class .div-right-side.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - only problem left is that on mobile the icon still sits very high. Any recommendation on how to get that to adjust to centered on mobile?

Comment: Thanks A TON for your help. Mobile looks great now. Only thing left is on desktop this seems to have skewed the sign up widget, bottom text and the last two icons are misaligned (which confuses me greatly).

Comment: I think you are missing something or you need to add all the clock inside this class content-area col-md-9 and after this you just need to add 1 div with "clear:both" option. And please compare one more thing is that above mobile code is conflicting with the your code that might be an issue or you are missing might be closing tag of the element.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, very sincerely. I had some misplaced divs. Looking good now!

Answer (score 0):

Using **Flex**: 
I have changed the structure a bit and tried to keep yours as much as I can. 
It's just a starting point, you can adjust accordingly.

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

p {
  background: transparent;
}

html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, ul, ol, li, p, a {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #FAD48B;
  margin: 15px 0 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

h2 {
  color: #FAD48B;
  margin: 20px 0 5px 0;
  padding: 2px;
}

h3 {
  color: #FAD48B;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

/*removes top nav put back once live!*/
.nav {
  display: none;
}

/*removes top nav !!put back once live!! */
.navbar-top-area.navbar-inverse {
  display: none;
}

/*removes menu !!put back once live!! */
.site-header .menu-container {
  display: none;
}

/* adds some yellow space below yodega loga in header*/
.site-header .container {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

/*attepmt to fix header to top*/
.header {
  position: fixed;
}

/*sell title = title "Sell Food Online with Yodega"*/
.sell-title {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 55px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-weight: bold;
  line-height: 55px;
}

/*sets paramaters of smaller benefits icon*/
.benefit-icon img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/*sets paramaters of larger benefits text*/
.benefit-title {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-decoration: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
}

/*sets paramaters of smaller benefits text*/
.benefit-detail {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.astericks {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 692pxpx) {
  .main, .small {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
}
/*changes outer background color of sign up form*/
#mailchimpsf_widget-2 {
  background: #3A3A3A;
}

/*changes signup form title font color*/
#mailchimpsf_widget-2 .widget-title {
  color: #FAD48C;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*removes signup box inner border*/
#mc_signup_form {
  border: none;
}

/*changes signup button colors*/
#mc_signup_submit {
  background: #FAD48C;
  color: #3A3A3A;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.clock-area {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.clock-area > .benefit-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.clock-area > .benefit-content > .benefit-title {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.clock-area > .benefit-icon {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sell-title">Sell Food Online with Yodega</div>

<div>

  <div class="clock-area">
    <div class="benefit-icon"><img src="http://www.yodega.com/images/blankClock.png" /></div>
    <div class="benefit-content">
      <div class="benefit-title blue">
        <div class="benefit-title blue"><b>Fast &amp; Easy Set Up – Start Selling Today</b></div>
      </div>
      <div class="benefit-detail purple">
        <div class="benefit-detail purple">store complete in 10 minutes with no programming required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clock-area">
    <div class="benefit-icon"><img src="http://www.yodega.com/images/blankClock.png" /></div>
    <div class="benefit-content">
      <div class="benefit-title blue">
        <div class="benefit-title blue"><b>Fast &amp; Easy Set Up – Start Selling Today</b></div>
      </div>
      <div class="benefit-detail purple">
        <div class="benefit-detail purple">store complete in 10 minutes with no programming required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clock-area">
    <div class="benefit-icon"><img src="http://www.yodega.com/images/blankClock.png" /></div>
    <div class="benefit-content">
      <div class="benefit-title blue">
        <div class="benefit-title blue"><b>Fast &amp; Easy Set Up – Start Selling Today</b></div>
      </div>
      <div class="benefit-detail purple">
        <div class="benefit-detail purple">store complete in 10 minutes with no programming required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="astericks">

  *4.9% + typical credit card processing fees **A vaild referral requires a recommendation within 1 month of referral store opening. Store must sell $300 of sales before referral rate reduction activates. Maximium .9% in reduction from standard fee rate
  from referral incentives.

</div>
```